# Visual Studio 2012 asks for EnterpriseLibrary 3.1 even if no reference in project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, enterprise-library

I have project which has no reference to Enterprise Library but the build keeps on searching for the file. I was wondering why it keeps on asking for the Enterprise Library even if I did not add any reference to it. After adding reference, I was asked adding logger settings in the config file.

Is there a default setting in VS2012 that forces the use of the EnterpriseLogging.Library of microsft?

How do I turn it off?

Note: The project type is a WCF Service Client tester. So I also add reference to a web service, but the web service does not have a reference to the Enterprise Library either.

Comment: No there isn't. You probably have a reference to a library that does use Enterprise Library, or a setting in your `app.config` that references it. EntLib 3.1 is ancient (released May 2007) and it's not included in any modern library or framework.

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought. the same project works fine in VS2008 before, the project is 6-8 years old. I checked the app config and it does not reference anything just a service reference. system.serviceModel section.